# parsing rss feed in php and dump to sql

Tags: php, sql, parsing, rss, feed

found this floating script to dump given feed into sql. however unable to save feed description and images separately in table. below is the part of code which is currently saving some contents but with empty columns.

any help or advise would be appreciated.

```
    $db = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if (!$db)
{
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
.....snip.............
```

**EDIT#1:**

studying [simplepie](http://simplepie.org/wiki/1.3/caching) script and its caching. will update should get it resolved tonight.

**EDIT#2:**
SQL query which was modified to include description and screengrab for the table contents.

> CREATE TABLE  `rss` (
>        ............snip........................

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjPtq.png)

**EDIT #3:**
thx robert for correcting me yes it was a quick copy paste from the original script and havent put correct query init. i had updated sql query and get things fixed however now the moded script needs more juice by retrieving a image link along with the post. i am using xpath to get each post image link however not able to incorporate the respective image with each row dump. both scripts are running perfectly at their individual grounds but i need more help in merging them together.

```
        require_once("./config.php");

    .......snip................
```

**EDIT#4:**
well it didnt work i mange to updated existing table with another script
i upvoted your answer but havent accepted it as correct answer due to this reason. might i failed to explain properly but my script is working like a charm and just missing some CSS.
thanks though for your help

*NOTE:* i snip original scripts from the post/

Comment: did you make it echo $item_insert_sql to see what the actual query looks like?

Comment: original post edited

Comment: if you have more than one image per post then i suggest creating a new table called "images" which is linked to the main table via some kind of a unique column (like item_id). Otherwise I'm not sure how you can cleanly insert multiple images into a single row

Comment: any idea about the single image insert with each item?

Comment: I'll update the answer

Comment: did the update in the original answer work?

Comment: to be honest it didnt work, however i managed to get it working by updating existing table with another script. i had upvoted your answer but havent accepted it as correct answer.
might i failed to explain properly but my script is working like a charm and just missing some CSS
thanks though for your help

Comment: ok.. this part of the script (which you snipped) stores images inside the $image array (which is a third parameter of the built-in preg_match function). So I'm not sure how it didn't work for you.

$has_image = preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $RSSitem, $image);

try doing <pre>print_r($images)</pre> right after and you'll see. So that's definitely the correct answer... anyways it's all good

Comment: much appreciated and thanks for the motivation in digging this project more and make it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot you're missing info inside "item_enclosure" and "item_status" columns, the rest is filled.

Problem is that your query doesn't try to insert those missing entries

```
        $item_insert_sql = "INSERT INTO rssingest(item_id, feed_url, item_title, item_date, item_description, item_url, fetch_date) VALUES ('" . $item_id . "', '" . $feed_url . "', '" . $item_title . "', '" . $item_date . "', '" . $item_description . "', '" . $item_url . "', '" . $fetch_date . "')";
```

^ Will never insert "item_enclosure" and "item_status" since the 2 columns are not part of the insert query...

You'd need to extract the 2 missing items and modify the insert query to:

```
        $item_insert_sql = "INSERT INTO rssingest(item_id, feed_url, item_title, item_date, item_description, item_url, fetch_date, item_enclosure, item_status) VALUES ('" . $item_id . "', '" . $feed_url . "', '" . $item_title . "', '" . $item_date . "', '" . $item_description . "', '" . $item_url . "', '" . $fetch_date . "', '" . $item_enclosure . "', '" . $item_status . "')";
```

You'll need to first define:

- $item_enclosure
- $item_status

Btw the query you pasted in your updated reply is wrong, it should start with "INSERT INTO" not "CREATE TABLE", you're not echoing the right query.

**UPDATE:**

In your original code there's this line

```
$has_image = preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $RSSitem, $image);
```

So right now if your code finds an image it should be putting it in an array called $image

Try print_r of $image to see in which array item it's stored, I think it will be $image[0][0] or $image[0]

So do the following to define the image URL (I'm guessing it's $image[0][0], but double check just in case):

```
$img_url = (isset($image)) ? $image[0][0] : "";
```

Then you'll need to update the insert query (i don't know what column name is used for the image so it's just an example):

```
    $item_insert_sql = "INSERT INTO rssingest(item_id, feed_url, item_title, item_date, item_description, item_url, fetch_date, item_enclosure, item_status, image_column) VALUES ('" . $item_id . "', '" . $feed_url . "', '" . $item_title . "', '" . $item_date . "', '" . $item_description . "', '" . $item_url . "', '" . $fetch_date . "', '" . $item_enclosure . "', '" . $item_status . "', '" . $img_url . "')";
```

Comment: thx robert for correcting me yes it was a quick copy paste from the original script and havent correct query init.

Comment: @kevin no problem, if the answer is correct feel free to hit "accept"